# Как обновить все пакеты сразу с помощью pip?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-3.9

Какой командой мне воспользоваться, чтобы с помощью `pip` обновить все пакеты сразу? Есть ли такая команда вообще? Если есть, зависит ли она от используемой ОС?

**P.S**. Не надо молча давать мне ссылки на какие-то другие сайты. Я и сам умею пользоваться гуглом. Мне нужен четкий ответ на поставленный вопрос.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Команда `pip freeze` выводит все установленные библиотеки в формате

```
lib1==0.1.0
lib2==3.2.1
...
```

А команде `pip install` можно передавать файл как раз в таком формате, соответственно:

```sh
pip freeze > requirements.txt
pip install -r requirements.txt -U
```

*(эти команды работает на любой системе)*

Вот так можно сделать на Linux:

```sh
pip freeze > requirements.txt && pip install -r requirements.txt -U
```

Comment: `pip install -U -r <(pip freeze)`

Comment: @wchistow, кстати, поздравляю с 3k!

Comment: @Глеб, спасибо :)

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy на винде такое выдает "The system cannot find the file specified". А вот вариант с requirements.txt что-то да делает. Правда прибит гвоздями к конкретному питону

Comment: `pip freeze > requirements.txt && pip install -r requirements.txt -U` и на `win` прекрасно работает